# Avoid creating a view for each AJAX function at CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to avoid creating a view for each AJAX function I am using at my controller. (as i don't manipulate the resulting data in any way and in most cases is just a boolean value)

I am using RequestHandler component at my controller:

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

And I added this in `routes.php`

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

I am trying to make this function to work, but I am getting a `null` value:

```
public function test(){
    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    $result = '1';
    $this->set('_serialize', $result);
}
```

To access to the `json` version of the function i use this URL finishing in `.json` to avoid loading any view:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/demoController/test.json
```

I have been following the steps from CakePHP documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#json-and-xml-views

What am I doing wrong? Why don't I get the expecting result and instead I get a `null`?

Also, if I try to to serialize some array, like this one:

```
$result = array('demo' => '1');
$this->set('_serialize', $result);
```

I'm getting this notice:

> **Notice** (8): Undefined index: 1 [**CORE\Cake\View\JsonView.php**, line **89**]Code Context                `$data = array();`
>                   `foreach ($serialize as $key) {`
>                       `$data[$key] = $this->viewVars[$key];`$view = null
>   $layout = null
>   $serialize = array(
>       'demo' => '1'
>   )
>   $data = array()
>   $key = '1'JsonView::render() - CORE\Cake\View\JsonView.php, line 89
>   Controller::render() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 957
>   Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 193
>   Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 161
>   require - APP\webroot\index.php, line 92
>   [main] - ROOT\index.php, line 42{"1":null}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand the documentation you have to specify a view variable and then refer to this variable when you use the `_serialize` key. This means your snippet would look like:

```
$result = '1';
$this->set('theResult', $result);
$this->set('_serialize', array('theResult'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the `.json` extension in the URL and the `Router::parseExtensions('json');` line in my `routes.php` file, so the [@dhofstet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803277/avoid-creating-a-view-for-each-ajax-function-at-cakephp#13804886) did not work for me.

My solution was to add the `renderAs()` call:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function my_ajax_action() {
    // do something
    $result = '1';
    $this->set('result', $result);
    $this->set('_serialize', array('result'));
    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create an element and render it.

```
function test() {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $result = array('demo' => '1');

    $this->set(compact('result'));
    $this->set('_serialize', array('result'));
    $this->render(DS.'Elements'.DS.'element_name');
}
```

[See docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)

Comment: But creating an element for each function is almost like creating a view. It doesn't solve me anything. What I am looking for is to reduce the number of "silly" views.

Comment: Well if the result is always a boolean (or always $result), you can use the same element for all actions.

Comment: But, where is the point of using the `serialize` method if I still have to deal with some kind of view? Isn't this method suppose to be to avoid using views? Documentation says: `This lets you skip defining view files for your controller actions if you don’t need to do any custom formatting before your data is converted into json/xml.`

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way is this. Works well for me.

```
public function fun() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');

    $result = array('data1' => 'hello', 'data2' => 'world');

    return json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty old question, with an accepted answer. If you're going to post something, it really ought to contain some words of explanation, maybe some links to documentation, something. A blurb of random code without so much as a comment is not very likely to be useful to future readers, or the OP who has had their answer for 3 years now.

Comment: The previous answers does not works for me. I think others users may face the same issue. That's why I added this code...as its the simplest way.

Comment: That's great, but explain that. There's no penalty for being clear, in fact, just the opposite. The words you added don't add anything -- explain yourself, that the other answers didn't work, why they didn't work, why this does work. How you arrived at this, some documentation for the methods you used, some documentation showing why the other answers might not have worked. That's the difference between a blurb of code that gets downvoted and an excellent late answer that rises above the accepted one because it is better.